# Chrome: weird scroll bar only during certain transition effects

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, scrollbar, css-transitions

I'm using jquery to apply following effects on my full screen background image:

```
function moveDown(){
    $('body').find('img').delay($delay*1000).animate({top: "+="+$distance}, $seconds*1000,'swing')
}
function zoomOut(){
    $('body').find('img').css({"transition":"all 6s linear","transform":"scale(1)"});
}
function zoomIn(){
    $('body').find('img').delay($delay*1000).animate(obj,6500,'linear');
}
```

this works great but only with the second function zoomOut() I'm experiencing a problem only in Chrome. While the transition is being performed I get a strange scrolling bar next to the normal scrolling bar and this one only shows up when the transition is in progress. As you can see on this image

[image: 2 scroll bars]

After the transition it again goes away and during the transition it shows up again??

Anybody any ideas on how to get rid of this second scroll bar?

Comment: Code would be helpful in diagnosing this problem, namely the CSS on the affected objects.

Comment: There are no affected objects, it's only the full screen bg image

Comment: Is the BG image an actual `background-iamge` or is it an `img` tag that is stretched to the width and height of the page??

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here that I'd be suspicious of to begin with.

You're using a javascript-based animation for moveDown and zoomIn, but then setting CSS animation values on zoomOut.  Try to stay consistent with your animations, and use CSS animations when possible as they perform better (use hardware acceleration, etc) compared to javascript animations.

When you set that CSS transition value, it's not being "de-applied" when another one of your animations fire, which means each incremental change done in moveDown or zoomIn will have the six second transition applied to them.

If you want a quick and dirty fix, you could put the following block in zoomIn and moveDown:

```
$('body img').css({'transition':'none', 'transform':'none'});
```

But ideally you would make all of these CSS transitions wrapped in a class, then just apply the class via JavaScript.

Just my 2¢

Comment: You're surely right about the consistent use of animations and will do so. But the proposed fix seems not to be the solution to this second appearing scroll bar...